# Axios post request doesnt get saved

Tags: reactjs, axios

[image][image][image: pic1][full code](https://github.com/JanLinhart/ackee) I am creating a recipe app with react and axios. When I try to add new recipe by submitting the form in the form.js, it doesnt get saved and displayed along the other recipes, it only gets printed in the console. I suppose its something with the axios. any idea?I would apreciate any advice a lot.

form.js

```
import React from 'react'
import './Form.css'
import {RecipeContext} from './RecipeContext';
import {useContext,useState} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

function Form() {
    const [nazev,setNazev]=useState('');
    const[uvodni,setUvodni]=useState('');
    const[ingredience,setIngredience]=useState('');
    const[postup,setPostup]=useState('');
    const[time,setTime]=useState(0);
    const [score,setScore]=useState(0);
    const{recipes,setRecipes}=useContext(RecipeContext)
    const onSubmit=e=>{
      const newRecipe={id:Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000000),
      description:postup,name:nazev,duration:time,info:uvodni,score:+score}
      
      e.preventDefault()
      
      axios.post("https://cookbook.ack.ee/api/v1/recipes", newRecipe)
      .then(res => setRecipes(res.data))
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
      
    
    }
    
    return (
        <>
        <button className="pridat" onClick={onSubmit}>+</button>
        <form className="form" >
          <p className="nazev">Název receptu</p>
          <input type="text" value={nazev}
          onChange={(e) => setNazev(e.target.value)}/>
          <input type="text" className="uvodni" placeholder="Úvodní text"
          value={uvodni}
          onChange={(e) => setUvodni(e.target.value)}/>
          <h2>Ingredience</h2>
          <input placeholder="Vaše ingredience" type="text"
          value={ingredience}
          onChange={(e) => setIngredience(e.target.value)}/>
          <button>+ Přidat</button>
          <input type="text" className="postup" placeholder="Postup"
          value={postup}
          onChange={(e) => setPostup(e.target.value)}/>
         <input type="text" placeholder="Čas" className="cas" value={time}
          onChange={(e) => setTime(e.target.value)}/>
        </form>
        </>
    )
          }

export default Form
```

recipecontext.js

```
import React,{useState,useEffect,createContext,useReducer} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import AppReducer from './AppReducer'


export const RecipeContext=createContext([[],() => {}]);

export default function RecipeProvider(props) {
    const[recipes,setRecipes]=useState([])
    const[state,dispatch]=useReducer(AppReducer,recipes)
    function addRecipe(id){
      dispatch({
        type:'ADD_RECIPE',
        payload:id
      })
    }
  
    useEffect(() => {
  axios.get('https://cookbook.ack.ee/api/v1/recipes?limit=10&offset=0')
  .then(res=>setRecipes(res.data))
  console.log(recipes)
    })   

    
  

    
    return (
       
<RecipeContext.Provider value={{recipes,setRecipes,addRecipe}}>
    {props.children}
</RecipeContext.Provider>
      
    )
}
```

recipelist.js

```
import {RecipeContext} from './RecipeContext';
import {useContext} from 'react';
import Recipe from './Recipe';
import './RecipeList.css'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'

function RecipeList() {

 const {recipes}=useContext(RecipeContext)
  
  return (
<>
<div className="navbar">
    <h1>Recepty</h1>
    <h3>Počet receptů:{recipes.length}</h3>
  <Link to="/pridat-recept"> <h2 className="plus">+</h2></Link> 
</div>
<div className="recipe-list">
{recipes.map(item=>(
    <Recipe name={item.name} id={item.id} duration={item.duration} score={item.score} key={item.id}/>
))}
</div>
</>

  );
}

export default RecipeList;
```

Comment: where are you trying to display your recipes? i cant see anywhere that.Can you paste that snippet in comment ?

Comment: I added it up there

Comment: add this in form.js: useEffect(()=>{console.log(recipes)},[recipes]) and tell me what you get ?

Comment: After submit, I get 1 more recipe written in the console

Comment: and what about in the UI ? are you getting your recipes rendered there?

Comment: No, I mean the useEffect is only console-logging it right?

Comment: there are two console.log for recipes one is inside recipeContext.js

Comment: update console.log with `useEffect(()=>{console.log("recipes"+recipes)},[recipes]) ` in your form.js this will let you know where is it getting printed

Comment: Okay, I can see, I where can I go from there?

Comment: can you paste your `recipes` output(from console.log) in your post?so that i can debug further

Comment: and recipes inside console.log in form.js is getting printed right ?

Comment: I just added it, the second one is showing the new recipe from form

Comment: instead of const{recipes,setRecipes}=useContext(RecipeContext) ,make it:const[recipes,setRecipes]=useState([]);

Comment: now it threw 422 error and didnt print the recipe

Comment: okay then undo the change and add this in form.js `useEffect(()=>{console.log("recipes"+JSON.stringify(recipes))},[recipes])`

Comment: the new log is on the very top

Comment: let's discuss it here:https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226177/debug-code

Comment: You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here.

Comment: thats unfortunate

Comment: now you can join

Comment: I feel like I am not able to respond in the chat but I am going to upload it now

Comment: here is the sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-ellis-wj8xd

Comment: And the chat really is not accessible for me